# 'use warnings' vs. '#!/usr/bin/perl -w' Is there a difference?

Tags: perl

I read that it is better to `use warnings;` instead of placing a `-w` at the end of the shebang.

What is the difference between the two?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> The warnings pragma is a replacement for the command line flag -w, but the pragma is limited to the enclosing block, while the flag is global. See [perllexwarn](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/perl/pod/perllexwarn.pod) for more information and the list of built-in warning categories.
>
> – [`warnings` documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/warnings)

The advantage of `use warnings` is that it can be switched off, and only affects the immediate scope.

Consider for example a module that uses operations that would emit warnings:

```
package Idiotic;
sub stuff {
    1 + undef;
}
```

Then we get a warning if we do

```
#!perl -w
use Idiotic; # oops, -w is global

Idiotic::stuff();
```

but don't get any warning with

```
#!perl
use warnings;  # pragmas are scoped, yay!
use Idiotic;

Idiotic::stuff();
```

Answer (score 7):

Yes, there is a difference, from [warnings](http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html):

> The warnings pragma is a replacement for the command line flag -w ,
>   but the pragma is limited to the enclosing block, while the flag is
>   global.

`-w` will enable warnings in included code (via `use`, etc.), and that may not be desirable.